# d3 selector for immediate children

Tags: d3.js

I can obviously do this:

```
d3.selectAll('div#some-div>ul')
```

But what if I'm using a DOM node or existing D3 selection:

```
d3.select(this).selectAll('ul')
```

will get me all descendent ULs. So, if

```
var div = d3.select('div')
```

got me this node:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>foo
      <ul><li>bar</li></ul>
    </li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

Then

```
var uls = div.selectAll('ul')
```

will get me two ULs. I guess I could distinguish a top level one like:

```
uls.filter(function() { return this.parentNode === div.node() }
```

So, I've answered my own question. Maybe it will be useful to someone. Or maybe someone can recommend a less ugly solution.

**Even better, Alain Dumesny, whose answer below is belatedly selected as correct, posted this as an issue to D3 and got the problem fixed, kludge-free, at the source!** (I would copy it in here for convenience, but then people might not scroll down and cast greatly deserved upvotes for his heroic feat.)

Comment: Your own answer is better than nrabinowitz's answer, because it does not have false positives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

d3 selection v2.0 should now have this built in with new `selection.selectChildren()` / `selection.selectChild()` methods - see https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/issues/243

Comment: :( I don't think this function exists in modern d3 anymore.
It is missing from V8.11.0

Answer (score 28):

I wouldn't have expected this to work, but it looks like D3 will sub-select any element that is a child of the selection *and* matches the selector - so this works:

```
d3.select(this).selectAll('div > ul');
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/g3aay/2/

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think to try that. Thanks! And now I have to go back and pull out my kludge.

Comment: This works for this concrete answers example code. If the `li` would have a `<div>` as well with the ´ul` in it, it would still return both of them. Is there a more general, working solution?

Comment: Maybe this is better: `d3.select('#foo').selectAll('#foo > ul')`

Answer (score 25):

If anyone is still interested, `d3.select(this.childNodes)` was helping me to solve my problem for picking all immediate children. Alternatively, you can use

```
selection.select(function(){
  return this.childNodes;
})
```

Comment: I believe this is the optimum solution

Comment: That's what worked for me: `d3.select(root).selectAll(function () { return root.childNodes }).data(data)`

Comment: @wonder.mice this only works if you have the root available as a variable. Perhaps you don't want that.

Answer (score 5):

@nrabinowitz's solution doesn't work all the time.

In my case, I was trying to do `d3.select(this).selectAll(".childNode > *")`.

So I was trying to get all the immediate children of .childNode. The problem is that this was a nested stack, so .childNode could also appear in the children, which was causing problems.

The best way I found is:

```
var child = d3.select(this).select(".childNode");
var sel = d3.select(this).selectAll(".childNode > *").filter(function() { 
    return this.parentNode == child.node();
});
```

Comment: I don't think that's going to work for you. If you're trying to do `d3.select(this).selectAll(".childNode > *")`, then `var child = d3.select(this).select(".childNode");` is only going to match the first .childNode, which isn't what you want. What about `var searchRoot = d3.select(<whatever>); searchRoot.selectAll('.childNode > *')`? (Which means nrabinowitz's answer remains the right one.)

Comment: Let's change my example to `d3.select(this).selectAll("p:first-child > *");` The problem is that  `> *` can also find `p:first-child` nodes that are nested. This is why I do a `select` on the `.childNode` in my example, because I only want to find a single one, and one that is closest to `this` node. Then I need to filter based on that. Another way would be to select `this` and filter  `this.parentNode.parentNode == thisNode;`

Answer (score 4):

The `selectAll` method relies on the `querySelectorAll` native method (in v4 at least).

It means you can use the `:scope` pseudo selector :

```
var uls = div.selectAll(':scope > ul')
```

the `:scope` pseudo selector is currently a [draft specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-scope-pseudo) and is not supported in all browsers yet. More information on `:scope` pseudo selector available on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution by Sigfrid, here is something I added to the prototype, in a project I work on.

```
  /**
   * Helper that allows to select direct children.
   * See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569670/d3-selector-for-immediate-children
   *
   * @param {string} selector
   * @returns {Selection}
   */
  d3.selectAll('__nonexisting__').__proto__.MYPREFIX_selectChildren = function (selector) {
    var expectedParent = this.node();
    return this.selectAll(selector).filter(
      function() {
        return this.parentNode === expectedParent;
      }
    );
  };
```

The way that I grab the prototype object looks a bit clumsy. Perhaps there is a better way.

The "MYPREFIX_" is meant to prevent name clashes.

The jsdoc `@returns {Selection}` is ambiguous, unfortunately this type is declared within a closure and has no global name referenceable by jsdoc (afaik).

Once this file is included, you can then do this:

```
d3.select('#some_id').MYPREFIX_selectChildren('ul')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like d3 used to have some functions built to address this exact problem- but for one reason or another they were removed.
By pasting this code into your program, you can add them back in again:

```
function childMatcher(selector) {
  return function(node) {
    return node.matches(selector);
  };
}

function children() {
  return this.children;
}

function childrenFilter(match) {
  return function() {
    return Array.prototype.filter.call(this.children, match);
  };
}

/**
 * Runs the css selector only on the immediate children.
 * See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569670/d3-selector-for-immediate-children
 * Use: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/commit/04e9e758c80161ed6b7b951081a5d5785229a8e6
 *
 * Example Input: selectChildren("form")
 */
d3.selection.prototype.selectChildren = function(match) {
  return this.selectAll(match == null ? children
      : childrenFilter(typeof match === "function" ? match : childMatcher(match)));
}

function childFind(match) {
  return function() {
    return Array.prototype.find.call(this.children, match);
  };
}

function childFirst() {
  return this.firstElementChild;
}

/**
 * Runs the css selector only on the immediate children and returns only the first match.
 * See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569670/d3-selector-for-immediate-children
 * Use: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/commit/04e9e758c80161ed6b7b951081a5d5785229a8e6
 *
 * Example Input: selectChild("form")
 */
d3.selection.prototype.selectChild = function(match) {
  return this.select(match == null ? childFirst
      : childFind(typeof match === "function" ? match : childMatcher(match)));
}
```

If you are using typescript, then here is the function declaration you can include in the same file:

```
declare module "d3" {
    interface Selection<GElement extends d3.BaseType, Datum, PElement extends d3.BaseType, PDatum> {
        selectChild(match: string | null | Function): Selection<GElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum>;
        selectChildren(match: string | null | Function): Selection<GElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum>;
    }
}
```

Here's a fiddle that implements this: https://jsfiddle.net/Kade333/drw3k49j/12/

Answer (score 0):

using the OP's example

```js
d3.select('ul')
```

does the job. From [the docs](https://d3js.org/d3-selection/selecting#select) it says:

> `d3.select` Selects the first element that matches the specified selector string ... If multiple elements match the selector, only the **first matching element** (in document order) will be selected

Answer (score -1):

For whatever it's worth after four years, `​d3.selectAll('#id > *')` can be used, e.g. in `​d3.selectAll('#id > *').remove()` to remove all children of an element with id=`id`

Comment: this targets every child on every 'descendant level'. It will fail to pick only the immediate children